# IBM Bluemix: Clusters cannot be created in this region without a Pay-As-You-Go account

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am currently trying to setup a blockchain network for my master's thesis.

For this purpose I used the guide for the free cluster on https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/setup/ .

Unfortunately by running the command "bx cs cluster-create --name blockchain" (Step 8) following error message is displayed:

> The 'machine-type' flag was not specified. So a free cluster will be created.
>   Creating cluster...
>   FAILED
>   Clusters cannot be created in this region without a Pay-As-You-Go account. Once you have a credit card on file, you can try out the service with a free cluster. https://console.bluemix.net/docs/billing-usage/how_charged.html#charges   (E0129)
>   Incident ID: 1c698c46-3537-4104-93e3-5aba9f81f5c6

As far as I understood it should be free to setup a sandbox blockchain on the IBM Platform. Is there any possibility to change the region in order to create a free cluster?

I am connecting from Germany, but connected to the IBM us-south region, like suggested in the guide: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/index.html#overview

Answer (score 1):

A while ago the ability to [create a free Kubernetes cluster moved from Lite accounts to PAYGO accounts](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_index.html#clusters). There are no charges for a free cluster, but you would need to convert your account.

If you are writing a master's thesis, you are probably part of a university. IBM is providing free resources via the [IBM Academic Initiative](https://onthehub.com/ibm/). There is a program that features cloud access and free usage of services and infrastructure. Discuss this with your university mentor.